# How to fix FileNotFoundException with CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, filenotfoundexception

EDIT/solution: FileNotFoundException is caused by file names with a #-sign in it

Original question:
I get an error on this piece of code (explicitly on the .send-line), which is executed for every chosen file on it´s own:

```
            With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
                .Open("GET", arrDateipfade(i), False)
                .send
                strInhalt = .responseText
            End With
```

Error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Ressource was not found

bei Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.InternalLateCall(Object o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)
bei Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateCall(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)
bei MyProgram.frmMyProgram.btnAusfuehren_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\topie\source\repos\MyProgram\MyProgram\Form1.vb:Line 314.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Check the value of `arrDateipfade(i)` when the exception occurs. Does it look correct?

Comment: It looks correct. It shows me C:\Users\topie\Desktop\Test\Aufnahme #5 XXXXXX_.html

Comment: Can you create just *one* object and use that instead of creating 6000 and more?

Comment: You'll need to keep an eye on memory usage with this code.  This is a COM object and you won't get the garbage collector to run often enough to get the object released soon enough.  The error message you get from running out of unmanaged address space is not necessarily very trustworthy.  Either use CreateObject() only once or count and call GC.Collect() every couple of hundred files.  Do favor WebClient.DownloadFile().

Comment: The # is the [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) (or name anchor) in a URL, so MSXML2.XMLHTTP could be cutting off the filename at that point.